# Fabian Gallina's python.el: imenu support

Tags: python, emacs

Can someone share instructions how can I get working imenu support with Fabian Gallina's python.el?

This is the commit that introduced imenu support, but my understanding of elisp is very low:

https://github.com/fgallina/python.el/commit/938e03cf6cdfcc30de84a4ec428aef9ff3c0c852

Currently I opened python file (major mode is python) and pressed `M+x imenu`, but got:

```
No items suitable for an index found in this buffer
```

PS `M-x python-imenu-` does not display any functions. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved it like this:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq imenu-create-index-function 'python-imenu-create-index)))
```